# my question is not formatted properly

Tags: support, markdown

I had a long text without spaces in my question and it is not aligned properly.Please have a look at the below question.how can I format such lengthy text?

[need help parsing an IIS log in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196223/need-help-parsing-an-iis-log-in-c)

Comment: @Jonathan, you fixed it, yea?

Comment: @o.k.w: Yes. I took the liberty of fixing it this time.

Answer (score 3):

Put backticks on both sides, or insert four spaces before it.